# Saving a data structure to a text file

Tags: c, data-structures, save

I am trying to implement a save system which allows me to save the user entered data of the "packet" structure that the user entered in the switch statement. Each record entered is stored in a single file separated via lines in plain text. It should also prompt the user what they would like to name the file, then the program should indicate how many records have been saved to the file, finally if no name is entered for the save file it should go back to the main menu.

as you can see from the void save function at the bottom, i have tried to implement this save system but when i run the program and choose S to save the records to the file it simply crashes after I enter a name for the file name. So if anyone could help me with this, that would be great.

UPDATE

After running the program through the debugger i get the following errors

UPDATE

Fixed bugging errors but the program crashes when entering a file name for the text file where the data will be saved too.

```
 #include <stdio.h>          //library including standard input and output functions
 #include <stdlib.h>         //library including exit and system functions used below
 #include <string.h>         //library including string functions used



 struct packet{
    int source;
    int destination;
    int type;               // Varibles for the structure
    int port;
    char data[50];
    char * filename;
};

void save(int, struct packet*); //function to save the records stored to a file

 int main ()
{
struct packet s[50];         //Array for structure input
char choice;
int NetworkPacket = 0, ii = 0;
int recordCount = 0;
struct packet *records;
struct packet *temp;
records = malloc(sizeof(struct packet));

        do{

    system("cls");
    puts("Please enter an option:\n");
    puts("'A' Add a packet:\n");
    puts("'D' to Display the Packet List:\n");                 // The Menu system
    puts("'S' to Save the Packets to a file:\n");
    puts("'C' to Clear the list of current saved packets:\n");
    puts(" or X to exit the program...\n");

    //wait for user input
    scanf("%c", &choice);   //take the first char of user input and assing the value to
                            //the variable choice using the address of (&) the variable
    if(choice == '\n')      //check to see that the character is not \n left over from the
        scanf("%c", &choice);   //previous choice made, if it is then we need to scan the input again

    switch (choice)
                    {
                        case 'A': system("cls"); //clear the screen

                        if(NetworkPacket==50)
                                {
                                    printf("No more network packets can be added");   // if statement giving the limit of 50 packets allowed to be added
                                    getch();        // User must press a key to continue
                                    continue;
                                }
                        else{
                                printf("\n****Adding a packet*****\n");
                                printf("Where is the packet from?\n");
                                scanf("%i", &s[NetworkPacket].source);
                                printf("Where is the packet going?\n");
                                scanf("%i", &s[NetworkPacket].destination);
                                printf("What type is the packet?\n");
                                scanf("%i", &s[NetworkPacket].type);                     // collecting the data of the packet inputted by the user
                                printf("What is the packet's port?\n");
                                scanf("%i", &s[NetworkPacket].port);
                                printf("Enter up to 50 characters of data.\n");
                                scanf("%s", s[NetworkPacket].data);
                                NetworkPacket++;
                            }break;

                        case 'D': system("cls"); //clear the screen
                                printf("\nDisplaying Infomation\n");

                                if(NetworkPacket==0)            // if statement stating to the user no records are shown if none are avalible
                                    {
                                        printf("no records yet, Please press any key to revert back to the main menu\n");
                                        getch();     // User must press a key to continue
                                        continue;
                                    }
                                else{
                                for(ii = 0; ii < NetworkPacket; ii++)
                                        {    // adds a 1 onto the NetworkPacket counter keeping a tally on the number of records stored.
                                            printf("\nSource: %d", s[ii].source);
                                            printf("\nDestination: %d", s[ii].destination );
                                            printf("\nType : %d", s[ii].type);// if statement giving the limit of 50 packets allowed to be added
                                            printf("\nPort : %d", s[ii].port);
                                            printf("\nData: %s\n---\n", s[ii].data);
                                        }getch();
                                    } break;

                        case 'S':
                            system("cls"); //clear the screen
                            save(NetworkPacket, records); //S was chosen so use the Save function
                        break;                       //the while condition is True so break the switch and loop around

                        case 4: break;
                        case 5: break;

                         default:system("cls"); printf("%c is not an option\n Try again...\n", choice);  // this message is shown if user doesn't input of one the case statment letters.


                         }
                         }while(choice!='X' );  // exits the program

                      return 0;

}


 void save(int rCount, struct packet *NetworkPacket){
  FILE *recordFile;                 //file handle
  char fileName[30] = { '\0'};      //string to store the file name
  int i;

  puts("Enter a filename to save the records :");   //ask the user for the filename
  scanf("%s", fileName);                            //store the filename: data input should be checked
                                                    //here in your program

  //try and open the file for writing and react accordingly if there is a problem
  if((recordFile = fopen(fileName,"w"))==NULL){
      printf("Couldn't open the file: %s\n",fileName);
      exit(1);
  }
  else{ //the file opened so print the records array of packets to it
      for(i=0;i<rCount;i++){
          fprintf(recordFile,"%04d %04d %04d %04d %s\n",
                  NetworkPacket[i].source,
                  NetworkPacket[i].destination,
                  NetworkPacket[i].type,
                  NetworkPacket[i].port,
                  NetworkPacket[i].port,
                  NetworkPacket[i].data);
      }
      fclose(recordFile);   //close the file
  }
```

}

Comment: Please format your code, it's difficult to read. Did you try to use a debugger ?

Comment: yes i have tried the debugger, it states

line 5: warning: "struc packet" declared inside parameter list

Comment: I also removed the break, thanks for that but obviously I still have that issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  case 'S': break;   <---- you have a break just after the case definition try remove it
   system("cls"); //clear th
```

Other case than 'S' work ?
and an advice you should use `fgets` instead of `scanf`.

Comment: it states line 5: warning: "struc packet" declared inside parameter list

Answer (score 0):

ok I have figured out how to fix the debugger errors, but the main issue is, when I am prompted to choose a filename for my save file, the program crashes

```
 line 5: warning: "struc packet" declared inside parameter list
```

So this happened because i declared the struc packet in a function without first stating what struc packet is. but that is now fixed

```
 line 22: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
```

I fixed this by giving it the actual pointer which points to the address of the Struc packet data

```
line 89: warning: passing arg 2 of 'save' makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

same solution as above.

I will now update the code

Comment: WHen you update the code **format** it correctly so it is readable. Correctly formatted code is much easier to maintain and to debug.